# Save data into Excel from SQLite and attach to email

Tags: android, excel, sqlite

I have an android application that save information into SQLite so i want my application to be able to take all the information from my database and email it as an Excel attachment to my Client email address.

**Example.**

**Sqlite database**

DATE ...     NAME...     SURNAME

12-10-2011 ...   Kgotso...   Smith

15-11-2012...Gerald...Ronaldo

And the result in excel should be the same with the heading.

sorry that i did not provide any code about sending the email because i do not have a clue how to start. the only steps that i did so far is to save information into sqlite database and able to retrieve it.

thank you in advance

Comment: This is beyond the scope of my knowledge but here is my two cents. Instead of exporting it to Excel, export it to a csv file which can be opened in Excel. If you feel that this is something which you might want to do then see this link http://paragchauhan2010.blogspot.in/2012/08/database-table-export-to-csv-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on how big and complex is your data. If this is something relatively small you may follow @Siddharth Roth comment and format your data ans comma separated (CSV) file. If you are adamant to use Excel format then you may want to look into ports of [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) or similar. If the size of that library is prohibitive or the port is not working your last resort would be to package your info into say JSON and submit to the remote server (for example a servlet engine such as Tomcat) that can run full POI and generate complex files.
Just remember not to do any of this on the main thread